# How to use parameter for type "List Subversion Tags (and more)" in a jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I want to write a jenkins pipeline job which uses a parameter of type  "List Subversion Tags (and more)". Can I do this and what is the syntax for doing it.

The description of the parameters directive only lists the standard parameters.

Can someone provide a sample script